# Remove variable label in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame df that looks like:

```
   Expenditure     Group Rank
1         18.8 Nontrauma  1.0
2         20.0 Nontrauma  2.0
3         20.1 Nontrauma  3.0
4         20.9 Nontrauma  4.5
5         20.9 Nontrauma  4.5
6         21.4 Nontrauma  6.0
7         22.0    Trauma  7.0
8         22.7 Nontrauma  8.0
9         22.9 Nontrauma  9.0
10        23.0    Trauma 10.0
11        24.5    Trauma 11.0
12        25.8    Trauma 12.0
13        30.0    Trauma 13.0
14        37.6    Trauma 14.0
15        38.5    Trauma 15.0
```

I would like to extract the rank-sum for the Trauma group as follows:

```
T = tapply(df$Rank, df$Group, sum)["Trauma"]
```

However, the variable T keeps the "Trauma" label, and passes that label along to all computations involving it. Is there a way of getting rid of the label, so that I remain with a plain numeric value?

Comment: Wrap it all in `unname()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
> sum(ddf[ddf$Group=='Trauma',]$Rank)
[1] 82
```